# Net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Кто знает, что вызывает ошибку **net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** ?
Данная ошибка появляется редко, но если случается - все запросы с этой вкладки заканчиваются этой ошибкой.
Хотя бы скажите, на чьей стороне эта ошибка возникает? Если на сервере, то что ее может вызывать?
P.s. Проверял в лисе и хроме. В хроме ошибка вылетает, а лиса просто молчит о невыполненных запросах

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возникает на сервере.
Лиса пишет:

> Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://.... Это может быть исправлено путем перемещения ресурса в тот же домен или включением CORS.

В PHP (у меня, по крайней мере) при проверке разрешенных доменов сайт по каким-то невероятным причинам не находит домен в списке разрешенных и не выдает заголовков Access-Control-Allow-Origin и Access-Control-Allow-Credentials.